# JQuery Remove and Add a Class in a Multi-Conditional Statement with Onclick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a multi level contact form. It changes to next level perfectly, but I have issue with the progress bar. I can't seem to pass an "active" class to the next step when the level changes.

Below is a sample HTML created for demonstration. Please assist

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // this works. It adds "active" to the step 1 on window load
  if ($(".section1").hasClass('current-section')) {
    $(".step1").addClass("active");
  }

  //this is meant to remove the class "active" from step 1 and add to step 2 but it doesn't work
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    if ($(".section2").hasClass('current-section')) {
      $(".step1").removeClass("active");
      $(".step2").addClass("active");
    }
  });

  //this is meant to remove the class "active" from step 2 and add to step 3 but it doesn't work
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    if ($(".section3").hasClass('current-section')) {
      $(".step2").removeClass("active");
      $(".step3").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li.active {
  background: orange;
}

div.current-section {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="step1">Step 1</li>
  <li class="step4">Step 2</li>
  <li class="step3">Step 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section1 current-section">
    section 1
    <button class="btn1">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section2">
    section 2
    <button class="btn2">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section3">
    section 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet and added the missing /, } and }) so now we have a [mcve]

Comment: Excellent snippet

Comment: and did you like my answer

Comment: Yes I did. I created a snippet inspired by your solution. Thank you @mplungjan

Comment: See my updated answer which handled prev and next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into DRY - don't repeat yourself

- use the same class for each same type
- if needed use IDs on the items if you need to access them directly
- use next() and parent() to access siblings

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn").click(function() {
    const $parent = $(this).parent()
    const $next = $(this).parent().next();
    const $prev = $(this).parent().prev();
    const nextBut = $(this).text() === "Next"
    if ($parent.is('.current-section')) {
      $parent.removeClass('current-section');
      if (nextBut && $next) $next.addClass('current-section');
      else if ($prev) $prev.addClass('current-section');
    }
    const $step = $(".step.active")
    const $prevStep = $step.prev();
    const $nextStep = $step.next();
    $step.removeClass('active');
    if (nextBut && $nextStep) $nextStep.addClass('active');
    else if ($prevStep) $prevStep.addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
li.active {
  background: orange;
}

.section {
  display: none;
}

div.current-section {
  background: limegreen;
}

.current-section {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="step active">Step 1</li>
  <li class="step">Step 2</li>
  <li class="step">Step 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section current-section">
    section 1
    <button class="btn">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    section 2
    <button class="btn">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    section 3
    <button class="btn">Prev</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setup like below:

```js
function reset() {
  $(".current-section").removeClass('current-section');
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //this works. It adds "active" to the step 1 on window load
  if ($(".section1").hasClass('current-section')) {
    $(".step1").addClass("active");
  }


  //this is meant to remove the class "active" from step 1 and add to step 2 
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".section2").addClass('current-section');
    $(".step2").addClass("active");
  });


  //this is meant to remove the class "active" from step 2 and add to step 3 
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".section3").addClass('current-section');
    $(".step3").addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
li.active {
  background: orange;
}

div.current-section {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="step1">Step 1
  </li>
  <li class="step2">Step 2
  </li>
  <li class="step3">Step 3
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section1 current-section">
    section 1
    <button class="btn1">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section2">
    section 2
    <button class="btn2">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section3">
    section 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan No worries

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided above are excellent. Though my code is more complex, "current-section" is controlled by another script in my code but I was greatly inspired by these solutions to make mine work. I was able to add a Back button.

Below is a snippet I made, inspired by the above solutions. I added a back button. 
This will be good for anyone who wants to make a multi step solution (it can be a simple slider) with a back and next button; hidden sections and progress bar

```js
function reset() {
  $(".current-section").removeClass('current-section');
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  if ($(".section1").hasClass('current-section')) {
    $(".step1").addClass("active");
  }
 
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".section2").addClass('current-section');
    $(".step2").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".section3").addClass('current-section');
    $(".step3").addClass("active");
  });
  
  $(".prvbtn1").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".step1").addClass("active");
    $(".section1").addClass('current-section');
  });
  
  $(".prvbtn2").click(function() {
    reset();
    $(".step2").addClass("active");
    $(".section2").addClass('current-section');
  });

});
```

```css
li.active {
  background: orange;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3 {
 display: none;
}
div.current-section {
  background: limegreen;
}
.current-section {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="step1">Step 1
  </li>
  <li class="step2">Step 2
  </li>
  <li class="step3">Step 3
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section1 current-section">
    section 1
    <button class="btn1">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="section2">
    section 2
    <button class="prvbtn1">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn2">Next</button>    
  </div>

  <div class="section3">
    section 3
    <button class="prvbtn2">Prev</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my answer. I have updated to handle your prev and next.

Comment: Way to go for unaccepting an answer 18 days later :) Much appreciated..